# join two pandas dataframes by two columns without order

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multiple-columns

I have two dataframes which look like this:

net1

|  | Gene_A | Gene_B | abs_dif | log2FC | omic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | RBL2 | ATOH7 | 0.277574 | 0.634319 | trans |
| 1 | RBL2 | USF2 | 0.276369 | 0.567421 | trans |
| 2 | RBL2 | RASA3 | 0.166101 | 0.474418 | trans |

net2

|  | Gene_A | Gene_B | abs_dif | log2FC | omic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ATOH7 | RBL2 | 0.277574 | 0.634319 | meth |
| 1 | RBL2 | USF2 | 0.276369 | 0.567421 | meth |
| 2 | RBL2 | Fernando | 0.166101 | 0.474418 | meth |

Each row represents a relationship. I am trying to merge both pandas dataframes based on columns 'Gene_A' and 'Gene_B', keeping both common and not common relationships. I am doing it using:

```
merged = pd.merge(net1, net2, how='outer', on=["Gene_A", "Gene_B"], indicator=True)
```

Which returns:

|  | Gene_A | Gene_B | abs_dif_x | log2FC_x | omic_x | abs_dif_y | log2FC_y | omic_y | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | RBL2 | ATOH7 | 0.277574 | 0.634319 | trans | nan | nan | nan | left_only |
| 1 | RBL2 | USF2 | 0.276369 | 0.567421 | trans | 0.276369 | 0.567421 | meth | both |
| 2 | ATOH7 | RBL2 | nan | nan | nan | 0.277574 | 0.634319 | meth | right_only |
| 3 | RBL2 | Fernando | nan | nan | nan | 0.166101 | 0.474418 | meth | right_only |

However, relationship `0` in both tables is basically the same, so the order of Gene_A and Gene_B should not be considered in the merging. Hence, the first row in the merged dataframe should be:

|  | Gene_A | Gene_B | abs_dif_x | log2FC_x | omic_x | abs_dif_y | log2FC_y | omic_y | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | RBL2 | ATOH7 | 0.277574 | 0.634319 | trans | 0.277574 | 0.634319 | meth | both |

How can I merge the dataframes without considering the order of the elements in the two columns on which dataframes are merged?

Comment: Accept and upvote  the solution u found helpful that keeps community motivated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this one of method i found which might be efficient but works :

for dataframe 1

```
net1['combined']=net1.apply(lambda x: str(set([x['Gene_A'], x['Gene_B']])),axis=1)
```

output:

```
  Gene_A    Gene_B   abs_dif    log2FC  omic              combined
0  ATOH7      RBL2  0.277574  0.634319  meth     {'ATOH7', 'RBL2'}
1   RBL2      USF2  0.276369  0.567421  meth      {'RBL2', 'USF2'}
2   RBL2  Fernando  0.166101  0.474418  meth  {'Fernando', 'RBL2'}
```

for dataframe2

```
net2['combined']=net2.apply(lambda x: str(set([x['Gene_A'], x['Gene_B']])),axis=1)
```

output:

```
  Gene_A Gene_B   abs_dif    log2FC   omic           combined
0   RBL2  ATOH7  0.277574  0.634319  trans  {'ATOH7', 'RBL2'}
1   RBL2   USF2  0.276369  0.567421  trans   {'RBL2', 'USF2'}
2   RBL2  RASA3  0.166101  0.474418  trans  {'RBL2', 'RASA3'}
```

for merging:

```
merged = pd.merge(net1, net2, how='outer', on=["combined"], indicator=True)
```

output:

```
  Gene_A_x  Gene_B_x  abs_dif_x  log2FC_x omic_x              combined Gene_A_y Gene_B_y  abs_dif_y  log2FC_y omic_y      _merge
0    ATOH7      RBL2   0.277574  0.634319   meth     {'ATOH7', 'RBL2'}     RBL2    ATOH7   0.277574  0.634319  trans        both
1     RBL2      USF2   0.276369  0.567421   meth      {'RBL2', 'USF2'}     RBL2     USF2   0.276369  0.567421  trans        both
2     RBL2  Fernando   0.166101  0.474418   meth  {'Fernando', 'RBL2'}      NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN    NaN   left_only
3      NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN    NaN     {'RBL2', 'RASA3'}     RBL2    RASA3   0.166101  0.474418  trans  right_only
```

Merged dataframe is as expected the unneccesary columns can be dropped using drop function.

Comment: Thanks! seems to work fine! Dropping and polishing the output will do the rest

Comment: Glad it helped:)

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` a `frozenset` on the columns you want to use as unordered key. Then use those as key to merge:

```
key1 = net1[['Gene_A', 'Gene_B']].apply(frozenset, axis=1)
key2 = net2[['Gene_A', 'Gene_B']].apply(frozenset, axis=1)
net1.merge(net2, left_on=key1, right_on=key2)
```

Output:

```
           key_0 Gene_A_x Gene_B_x  abs_dif_x  log2FC_x omic_x Gene_A_y Gene_B_y  abs_dif_y  log2FC_y omic_y
0  (ATOH7, RBL2)     RBL2    ATOH7   0.277574  0.634319  trans    ATOH7     RBL2   0.277574  0.634319   meth
1   (USF2, RBL2)     RBL2     USF2   0.276369  0.567421  trans     RBL2     USF2   0.276369  0.567421   meth
```

*NB. As you have identical column names, you might need to perform some cleanup.*

Comment: using frozenset was creative i used string instead cause set is not hashable.

Comment: @navaneeth yes, frozensets are hashable. One could also use sorted tuples ;)

Comment: In addition to other users comments, the output is not the corresponding full join

Comment: @Fernando I provided the minimal method for clarity, it is trivial to add whichever parameters you want (`how='outer', indicator=True`) for the merge ;)